# product image zoom in zen cart?

Tags: php, jquery-plugins, plugins, zen-cart, zen

I need help on the `how can i zoom image of the product in zen cart ?`

I am try the **jqzoom plugins** but not shown any effect also not found any option `admin->configuration->jqzoom`

I am use the `zen cart version 1.5.0.`
is jqzoom is compatible with zen cart version 1.5.0?

or suggest any other plugins which compatible with zen cart version 1.5.0

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As zencart 1.5.0 add admin type and admin role functionality so you need to register your page to display in admin panel menu.

How to register page from admin area. ?

```
1. go to :  Admin Access Management - > Admin Page Registration
2. fill form and click on insert.
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use the jq zen cart plugin?

I couldnt find one that worked with v1.5, luckily its really easy to set up anyway, heres how i did it: Download the normal version jqzoom, rename the css and js files so that they began with script_ and style and drop them into the appropriate folders in your template, you then go in and edit the file includes/templates/default_template/templates/tpl_modules_main_product_image.php, add a class to the image link (as per jqzoom instruction) and save it to your template includes/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/templates/tpl_modules_main_product_image.php. you then call it with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.yourclass').jqzoom();
});
```

put this either in your own javascript file or at the bottom of the jqzoom javascript, you can set various options when calling the script -check out jqzoom docs